# Use cookies in pagination

Tags: pagination, cookies

I am having a problem with cookies. I am using page breakers for long content post. I initialize a cookie with value 1 once you are reading the post. For each page breaker or let say page (from pagination) i increment this cookie value plus 1. But at this moment wordpress caches the cookie for each page.

Example if i am in page 2 and the cookie value is 2, and i go back at page one the cookie value should be 3 but it is 1. At this moment there are two cookies shown with the same name but with two values 2 and 1.

Comment: It is quite impossible to help if you do not post your code. File an [edit] and add your code and all other relevant info

Answer (score -1):

The problem was with domain. I should have set the cookie domain globally. `/`